# Auto execute the command to the terminal after double click the file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to auto input the command to the terminal when double clicking the script.

## something like:

cd/xxx/xxx

dpkg -i xxxxxxxxx

chmod +x xxxxx

ll xxxx

cd ~

/opt/xxxxxxxxxx

I want to execute all these commands with one click.

## What i Found out:

#!/bin/bash

cd/xxx/xxx

dpkg -i xxxxxxxxx

chmod +x xxxxx

ll xxxx

cd ~

/opt/xxxxxxxxxx

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: What is exactly your goal?

Comment: These commands are to set up the settings, the users don't want to key in the commands one by one. They want to have something like double clicking a script/file than auto run these commands in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The way to have commands executed after a user clicks an icon in the gui would be to include these commands in a script, and then create a launcher, i.e. a .desktop file, that calls the script in an appropriate location. Then, the icon will appear in the user's menu and can be executed from there.

**For your current user only**
Your script can reside in `~/bin`. In Ubuntu, `~/bin` is automatically added to the PATH so that you (only you as a user) can execute the script simply by typing its name. The executable bit of the script must be set.

Your `.desktop` file that calls the script should reside in `.local/share/applications`. Any desktop files there will populate the menu *of the current user* only.

**System wide**

You need root permissions to implement this.

Your script should reside in a directory that is included in the PATH. Then, anyone will be able to execute the script by typing its name (script has to be set executable). `/usr/local/bin` could be a good place for these custom scripts.

Your .desktop file should reside in `/usr/share/applications`. This way, it will populate the menu of any user on the system.

The end result is that the end-user can execute the commands by clicking the icon.